# Is there any badge for asking hot questions so many times?

Tags: discussion, badge-request, hot-questions

Is there any badge awarded to people whose questions appear many times on the list of Stack Exchange's hot questions (the upper left menu bar of the site). If there is no such badge, I would like to suggest it. Note that this badge is different from badges like "Notable Question" or "Nice Question" or any other badge that deals with high *number of page views* and *votes*. A question with many page views or votes may never appear on the list of Hot Questions (because it has gained its votes and views through a long period of time).

Comment: Do you mean simultaneously or over a period of time?

Comment: @CodingMash I mean over a period of time. For example, someone asks 10 different questions on 10 SE sites over a period of time (no matter how much time passes between asking questions), and say 6 of them appear on the list of hot questions. In my opinion, this is an indication that this person is asking really nice questions.

Comment: The idea is nice though it may or may not be the perfect indication to judge a user's commitment. 
Reason as you hinted yourself, some really good questions get attention over a period of time. And some less good questions get attention instantly.